# How to Transparentize a `Region` plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

If a region which is drawn by `Region` function is a 2D area, we can see the region. However, if a region is a 3D region, we sometimes cannot see the region when the region is inside of something because there seems to be no option to make it transparent for `Region` function. I use Mathematica 11.1.1.0 on Windows7.

---

For example,
If the region I want to draw is a 2D area, `Region` show us what we want:

```
region = Disk[{0, 0}, 1];
complement = BooleanRegion[Not, {region}];
Region[complement]
```

[image: 2D case]

However, if the region is a 3D region, `Region` does not give us a relevant draw:

```
region2 = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1];
complement2 = BooleanRegion[Not, {region2}];
Region[complement2]
```

[image: 3D case]

Then, do you know any good workaround for this frustrating matter?
I know if I convert the region into a set of inequality equations, I can use `RegionPlot` function and the function has an opacity option but I want to know other solutions.

Any advise is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cheat and convert into a (`Boundary`)`MeshRegion`, and then use `MeshCellStyle`.

I'll use a more interesting example:

```
region2 = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1];
complement2 = BooleanRegion[Not, {region2}];
reg = Region[complement2];

BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg, MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> Opacity[1/2]}]
```

[image: discretized region]

Comment: Oh, I also misunderstood about `Sphere`, it doesn't contain the balk region.

Comment: This does not appear to work anymore in Mathematica 12.1

Comment: `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg, 
 MeshCellStyle -> {{All} -> Opacity[0.5]}]` will make the box transparent (though the mesh is visible), but rather than a sphere, a tiny triangle appears inside of it...

Comment: It's slightly easier to see the tiny tetrahedron(?) with `Show[reg, PlotRange -> {All, 0}]`.

Comment: @alessandro, indeed, a lot seems to have changed in intervening versions... o well.